# Blacklist URLs with headless Chrome

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara, webmock

I'm trying to block URLs in my specs, achieving something like I had when using `capybara_webkit`:

```
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.block_url("*google*")
  config.allow_url('*my_website.com')
end
```

After reading [this article](http://www.benjaminfleischer.com/set-up-headless-chrome-with-capybara), I tried to do something like:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'

module WebmockConfig
  def self.default_disabled_urls
    [
      '*google*'
    ]
  end
end

WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: WebmockConfig.default_disabled_urls)
```

but I'm getting

> Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST http://127.0.0.1/session

even if that should be solved by `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)`.

When running the specs without `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: WebmockConfig.default_disabled_urls)`, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `capybara-webkit` white/blacklisting affects the requests made by the browser, whereas WebMock can only affect requests made by your app. This means `WebMock` is useless for what you want since it wouldn't actually stop your browser from loading anything from google, etc.  To do that while using the selenium driver you need to use a programmable proxy like [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) which will allow you to customize the responses for any matching requests the browser makes.

To configure a driver using headless chrome and puffing_billy you could do something like

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
 browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
 browser_options.headless!
 browser_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=#{Billy.proxy.host}:#{Billy.proxy.port}")
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
end
```

Whether or not you need any other options is dependent on your system config, etc but you should be able to tell by looking at your current driver registration.

Comment: Hey Thomas. From what I can read here https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy#setup-for-capybara it's not possible to use my actual driver (`headless_chrome`) with `puffing-billy` fucntionalities?

Comment: @fabersky It can be used with any Capybara driver that supports a proxy - you just need to register your own custom driver configuration - https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy#customising-the-javascript-driver and https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/blob/master/lib/billy/browsers/capybara.rb .  I've added a configuration that could be used with headless chrome to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The `allow_localhost: true` settings are overwritten by `allow: WebmockConfig.default_disabled_urls` you have to call `WebMock.disable_net_connect!` once with both settings or by adding `'localhost', '127.0.0.1'` entries into `self.default_disabled_urls`

Comment: Hey @narze I know how to add multiple urls in `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow:` by adding an array of URLs, but how can I combine `allow_localhost` and `allow`?

Comment: @fabersky You can try `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow: [...], allow_localhost: true)` and see if it works or not. If not, manually add localhost ips into `allow` array

Comment: anyway, even if i achieve that in this way, I don't think it would be the expected result. What I want to achieve is just blocking requests from blacklisted URLs. This way, my specs will probably fail once they will get a request from one of that URLs.